# Rotate HTML page by 90 Degrees and allow for scrolling of content

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page that has a table with many rows. I would like to display it on a monitor that has been manually flipped on its side - 90 Degrees clockwise.

The device that sends the feed to the monitor is not in my control and it will always have a browser in landscape orientation.

The following CSS works perfectly for flipping the content of the screen on its side :

```
html {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transform-origin: right;
      transform: translate(-100vw, 0) rotate(180deg);
      writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

The issue now is that the scrollbar/scrolling does not behave as one would expect.

Below are images that aim to explain what is wrong with this solution.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is a jsFiddle that shows the issue in action : https://jsfiddle.net/8e5o6fbr/

I am hoping to find a solution where if I rotate the content of the page, I can scroll the content as one would expect to scroll the content.

Comment: If you remove the `transform` from the `html`, and just add `transform: rotate(180deg);` to the body, it seems to achieve what you want (the scrollbar will be on the "wrong" side, but that doesn't seem like a big problem)

Comment: Thank you, that does solve the question I originally asked. But it appears that I am now unable to calculate the left position of the scroll bar in a predictable manner because the left most side of the screen is not point 0. its a large negative number (that changes when dynamic content lands in the table)